# the labels are too far away from the input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the labels are too far away from the input boxes

[image]

this can be confusing for users to keep track of what they are filling in.

```html
<link href="http://www.qlbusiness.com/static/ui/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>QL Business</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="wrapper">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Customer Service</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/account/do_login" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px; width: 75%">


            <div class="ui ignored positive icon message">
                <i class="edit icon"></i>

                <div class="content">
                    <h3 class="header">Insert Ad</h3>
                    Your ad will be reviewed according to the rules of our site. After approval, it will be published
                    for a period
                    of 60 days. Thanks for using our site!
                </div>
            </div>


            <form method="post" action="http://www.qlbusiness.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6ZHOY_ie_HHe69JmSQgOA3W9L3ezf92_z1ZYXubImy_QrcYi0L5bfiv1-nW8nUhxRQBFmdmXkJSEewM0vnauBJ0HjaTJja_s_8KTeg15_fFX8quBGGV91TIBYIK5jtfOe-GXx7E/ALBNUaYAAAAAV3gEGGfIbS9adBDsyVar3DnoppdYi7eu/" name="formular" class="ui form" accept-charset="UTF-8"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">


                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="required two wide field">
                        <label>Name</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <input size="35" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="required two wide field">
                        <label>Email</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <input size="35" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="two wide field">
                        <label>Phone</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number">

                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                            <input id="example-id" type="checkbox" checked>
                            <label for="example-id">View phone number on site</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="required two wide field">
                        <label>Category</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <select class="ui dropdown" name="category_group">
                            <option value="0">«All categories»</option>
                            <option value="1000" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 195); font-weight: bold;"
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    id="cat1000">
                                -- Real estate --
                            </option>
                            <option value="1020" id="cat1020">
                                Houses
                            </option>
                            <option value="1010" id="cat1010">
                                Apartments
                            </option>
                            <option value="1030" id="cat1030">
                                Vacation homes
                            </option>
                            <option value="1050" id="cat1050">
                                Offices
                            </option>
                            <option value="1080" id="cat1080">
                                Land
                            </option>
                            <option value="1100" id="cat1100">
                                Flatmates/Paying Guest
                            </option>
                            <option value="1090" id="cat1090">
                                Other
                            </option>

                            <option value="2000" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 195); font-weight: bold;"
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    id="cat2000">

                                -- Vehicles --

                            </option>

                            <option value="2010" id="cat2010">
                                Cars

                            </option>

                            <option value="2030" id="cat2030">
                                Motorcycles

                            </option>

                            <option value="2040" id="cat2040">
                                Accessories &amp; parts

                            </option>

                            <option value="2080" id="cat2080">
                                Trucks

                            </option>

                            <option value="2070" id="cat2070">
                                Other vehicles

                            </option>

                            <option value="3000" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 195); font-weight: bold;"
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    id="cat3000">

                                -- Home &amp; Personal items --

                            </option>

                            <option value="3040" id="cat3040">
                                Home &amp; Garden

                            </option>

                            <option value="3050" id="cat3050">
                                Clothing

                            </option>

                            <option value="3030" id="cat3030">
                                For Kids (Toys &amp; Clothes)

                            </option>

                            <option value="3060" id="cat3060">
                                Jewelry &amp; Watches

                            </option>

                            <option value="4000" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 195); font-weight: bold;"
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    id="cat4000">

                                -- Leisure, Sports &amp; hobby --

                            </option>

                            <option value="4010" id="cat4010">
                                Hobbies

                            </option>

                            <option value="4020" id="cat4020">
                                Sports &amp; Bicycles

                            </option>

                            <option value="4040" id="cat4040">
                                Movies, Books &amp; Magazines

                            </option>

                            <option value="4030" id="cat4030">
                                Pets

                            </option>

                            <option value="4090" id="cat4090">
                                Tickets

                            </option>

                            <option value="4060" id="cat4060">
                                Art &amp; Collectibles

                            </option>

                            <option value="4070" id="cat4070">
                                Music &amp; Instruments

                            </option>

                            <option value="5000" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 195); font-weight: bold;"
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    id="cat5000">

                                -- Electronics --

                            </option>

                            <option value="5030" id="cat5030">
                                Computers &amp; Accessories

                            </option>

                            <option value="5020" id="cat5020">
                                TV, Audio, Video, Cameras

                            </option>

                            <option value="5010" id="cat5010">
                                Cellphones &amp; gadgets

                            </option>

                            <option value="5040" id="cat5040">
                                Video games &amp; consoles

                            </option>

                            <option value="6000" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 195); font-weight: bold;"
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    id="cat6000">

                                -- Jobs &amp; Services --

                            </option>

                            <option value="6010" id="cat6010">
                                Job offers

                            </option>

                            <option value="6020" id="cat6020">
                                Resumes

                            </option>

                            <option value="6030" id="cat6030">
                                Services

                            </option>

                            <option value="6040" id="cat6040">
                                Classes

                            </option>

                            <option value="6090" id="cat6090">
                                Professional/Office equipment

                            </option>

                            <option value="7000" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 195); font-weight: bold;"
                                    disabled="disabled"
                                    id="cat7000">

                                -- --

                            </option>

                            <option value="7010" id="cat7010">
                                Other

                            </option>

                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="two wide required field">
                        <label>State</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <select class="ui dropdown" onchange="cities(this);document.getElementById('area').display='';"
                                name="region" id="region">
                            <option value="">«Choose state»</option>
                            <option value="7089183">

                                Alabama
                            </option>
                            <option value="7091183">

                                Alaska
                            </option>
                            <option value="7088186">

                                Arizona
                            </option>
                            <option value="7102183">

                                Arkansas
                            </option>
                            <option value="7095185">

                                California
                            </option>
                            <option value="7094186">

                                Colorado
                            </option>
                            <option value="7097187">

                                Connecticut
                            </option>
                            <option value="7088187">

                                Delaware
                            </option>
                            <option value="7101184">

                                Florida
                            </option>
                            <option value="7090186">

                                Georgia
                            </option>
                            <option value="7095186">

                                Hawaii
                            </option>
                            <option value="7095187">

                                Idaho
                            </option>
                            <option value="7101185">

                                Illinois
                            </option>
                            <option value="7090187">

                                Indiana
                            </option>
                            <option value="7102184">

                                Iowa
                            </option>
                            <option value="7092184">

                                Kansas
                            </option>
                            <option value="7098186">

                                Kentucky
                            </option>
                            <option value="7100184">

                                Louisiana
                            </option>
                            <option value="7091184">

                                Maine
                            </option>

                            <option value="7089185">

                                Maryland
                            </option>

                            <option value="7096187">

                                Massachusetts
                            </option>
                            <option value="7096188">

                                Michigan
                            </option>
                            <option value="7098188">

                                Minnesota
                            </option>
                            <option value="7102185">

                                Mississippi
                            </option>
                            <option value="7094187">

                                Missouri
                            </option>
                            <option value="7093186">

                                Montana
                            </option>
                            <option value="7091185">

                                Nebraska
                            </option>
                            <option value="7102186">

                                Nevada
                            </option>
                            <option value="7093187">

                                New Hampshire
                            </option>
                            <option value="7090188">

                                New Jersey
                            </option>
                            <option value="7094188">

                                New Mexico
                            </option>
                            <!--               <option value="7099184">-->
                            <option value="6370570371334144">
                                New York
                            </option>
                            <option value="7101186">

                                North Carolina
                            </option>
                            <option value="7092185">

                                North Dakota
                            </option>
                            <option value="7098189">

                                Ohio
                            </option>
                            <option value="7091186">

                                Oklahoma
                            </option>
                            <option value="7097188">

                                Oregon
                            </option>
                            <option value="7088189">

                                Pennsylvania
                            </option>
                            <option value="7098190">

                                Rhode Island
                            </option>
                            <option value="7093188">

                                South Carolina
                            </option>

                            <option value="7094189">

                                South Dakota
                            </option>
                            <option value="7097189">

                                Tennessee
                            </option>
                            <option value="7101187">

                                Texas
                            </option>
                            <option value="7090189">

                                Utah
                            </option>
                            <option value="7088190">

                                Vermont
                            </option>
                            <option value="7097190">

                                Virginia
                            </option>
                            <option value="7099185">

                                Washington
                            </option>
                            <option value="7091187">

                                West Virginia
                            </option>
                            <option value="7098191">

                                Wisconsin
                            </option>
                            <option value="7101188">

                                Wyoming
                            </option>

                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>


              <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="two required wide field">
                        <label>City</label>

                    </div>

                    <div id="cities" class="five wide field">
                        <select class="ui dropdown" onchange="cities(this);document.getElementById('area').display='';"
                                name="region" id="region">
                            <option value="">«Choose city»</option>




                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>




                <div class="required inline field">

                    <div class="fields"><label class="two wide field">Type</label>

                        <div class="inline field">
                            <input type="radio" name="type" checked="checked">
                            <label>For sale</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline field">
                            <input type="radio" name="type">
                            <label>Want to buy</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="required two wide field">
                        <label>Title</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <input size="55" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="required two wide field">
                        <label>Text</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inline fields">
                    <div class="required two wide field">
                        <label>Price</label>

                    </div>

                    <div class="five wide field">
                        <div class="ui right labeled input">
                            <div class="ui label">
                                $</div>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Amount">

                            <div class="ui basic label">
                                .00
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="inline field">
                    <label class="two wide field">Image</label>
                    <input name="image1" size="35" id="image1" type="file">
                </div>

                <div class="inline field">
                    <label class="two wide field">Image</label>
                    <input name="image2a" size="35" id="image2a" type="file">
                </div>
                <div class="inline field">
                    <label class="two wide field">Image</label>
                    <input name="image3" size="35" id="image3" type="file">
                </div>
                <div class="inline field">
                    <label class="two wide field">Image</label>
                    <input name="image4" size="35" id="image4" type="file">
                </div>
                <div class="inline field">
                    <label class="two wide field">Image</label>
                    <input name="image5" size="35" id="image5" type="file">
                </div>


                <div class="required field">
                    <div class="ui checkbox">
                        <input id="terms" type="checkbox" checked>
                        <label for="terms">I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

      <div class="inline field">
                    <label class="two wide field"></label>
                        <div class="ui progress blue seven wide field">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="percent">0%</div>
                </div>
                <div id="status"></div>
                </div>



                <br>

                <div class="ui field">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui button"/>
                </div>
                <div class="ui error message"></div>
            </form>
        <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 QL Business, Inc.</p>
         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/koolbusiness" target="_blank">
<button class="ui circular facebook button">
  <i class="facebook icon"></i>
  Facebook
</button></a>
    <!--
<button class="ui twitter button">
  <i class="twitter icon"></i>
  Twitter
</button>-->
   <a href="https://plus.google.com/b/101588786083596465725/101588786083596465725" target="_blank">
<button class="ui circular google plus button">
  <i class="google plus icon"></i>
  Google Plus
</button>
</a>
    </footer>
        </div>
    </div>


    <hr>


</div>
```

How can I decrease the distance between the labels and the input boxes?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<div class="required two wide field">
```

To

```
<div class="required two narrow field">
```

Comment: You need to change wide to narrow on the left fields.
The divs in which you have the labels. Do a google search for bootstrap grid

Comment: It didn't work. I don't know why. I'm trying to make grids instead with semantic-ui. Changing to narrow does nothing or nearly nothing for me.